# Using History.js to store data and then use data for ajax loading for pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a completely ajaxified website. The following is the code for ajax loading for pages. I'm trying to use history.js into this code, but after incorporating the the code, it only changes the url but not the content. What I trying to do is, when the state changes, data which is stored in the state and then use ajax to load the page.

**Before history.js**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navButton").click(function() {
        $("#main").fadeOut();
        var a = $(this).attr('id');
        $.post('functions/ajax.php?id='+a, {}, function(response){
            //$('#container').html(unescape(response));
            ///$('#container').fadeIn();
            setTimeout("finishAjax('main', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
        });
    });
});
function finishAjax(id, response){
    $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
    $('#'+id).fadeIn();
}
```

**After history.js:**

```
$(function() {
    ajaxifyLinks();
    $(".navButton").click(function() {
        $("#main").fadeOut();
        var a = $(this).attr('id');
        $.post('functions/ajax.php?id='+a, {}, function(response){
            //$('#container').html(unescape(response));
            ///$('#container').fadeIn();
            setTimeout("finishAjax('main', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
        });
    });
});
function ajaxifyLinks() {
    $(".navButton").click(function() {
        var a = $(this).attr('id');
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        History.pushState(a, document.title, '?action='+name);
        return false;
    });
}
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function() {
    var State = History.getState();
    var data = State.data;
    $("#main").fadeOut();
    $.post('functions/ajax.php?id='+data, {}, function(response){
        //$('#container').html(unescape(response));
        ///$('#container').fadeIn();
        setTimeout("finishAjax('main', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
    });
    ajaxifyLinks();
});
function finishAjax(id, response){
    $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
    $('#'+id).fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: This is perhaps unrelated, but were you intending to extend the `.nav-button`'s `click` event, immediately after invoking `ajaxifyLinks()`? (Line 3 of 'after history.js')

Comment: Yes, thats what I have done here. So, when I go back, there won't be 2 ajax calls, which will get buggy.

Comment: It's been 3 days since I posted this question, I'm starting to doubt that there is any solution, will wait for 2 days and then I'll work on the ajax calls from the scratch.

Comment: If you print `response` and `id` to the console, in `finishAjax()`, does it show the correct values?

Comment: If it doesn't, try changing the `setTimeout("finishAjax('main',...)", 400)` to `setTimeout(finishAjax('main', escape(response)), 400)`, I'm thinking maybe there's an issue with the way your parameters are being passed. This way, you also should not need to escape and then unescape the response. (unescape has been deprecated, in favour of decodeURI. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape)

Comment: I used console.log in the finishAjax function, when I first click any button, it will go `main
user
main` and then if I click the same button again, `main
user`
I have tried changing the setTimeout, but then nothing comes up.

Comment: Hmm, could I get you to replicate your issue on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)? You can simply remove the $.post() call, and execute `setTimeout()` directly, as I don't think that's the issue. I'm going to head off for the night, but will take a look at this again in the morning.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/MiB3Avenger/8bz8juzt/1/ There you go, if you want the website link where it is temporarily available, go here http://testsocial.ml/?action=login

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129468/discussion-between-xtrasimplicity-and-chinmay-nagrale).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any of those interested how I managed to do it, here is the code:

```
$(function() {
  ajaxifyLinks();
  $(".navButton").click(function() {
       $("#main").fadeOut();
       var a = $(this).attr('id');
       $.post('../functions/ajax.php?id='+a, {}, function(response){
         setTimeout(finishAjax('main', escape(response)), 400);
    });
  });
});

function ajaxifyLinks() {
       $(".navButton").click(function() {
          var a = $(this).attr('id');
          var name = $(this).attr('name');
          History.pushState({data : a}, document.title, '?action='+name);
          return false;
  });
}

$(window).on('popstate', function () {
       $("#main").fadeOut();
       d = History.getState();
       $.post('../functions/ajax.php?id='+d.data.data, {}, function(response){
         setTimeout(finishAjax('main', escape(response)), 400);
   });
});

function finishAjax(id, response) {
     $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
     $('#'+id).fadeIn();
     console.log(response);
     console.log(id);
}
```

I used `console.log` in the popstate function to check if the data is stored or not. I found out that it got stored in `data.data`. The only problem in this code is that when you check the console for response & id logs, it is registered twice. But when you go back in history, the last used page is loaded and not the same.

Any updates/tweaks in the code is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fiddle that you provided in the comments on your question, it appears that this issue was caused by the call to `finishAjax()`. I have [updated your fiddle with some minor changes](https://jsfiddle.net/8bz8juzt/2/), which should solve the problem. The changes are as follows:

- Removed the string concatenation (`'"+escape(response)+"'` ) from the `response` parameter of `finishAjax()`.
  This concatenation, when combined with the  following change, results in the escaped string being surrounded by single quotes. When the parameter is later unescaped, it attempts to unescape the single quotes, too.

Theoretically, you shouldn't even need to escape/unescape the `response` variable, as the variable's value will be passed.

- Switched the call to finishAjax() from within `setTimeout()` such that it is a function, rather than a string. This is *slightly* more efficient, and may also make refactoring just that tiny bit easier (as it will appear in your IDE's 'find usage' functionality).

Hope this helps!

**Edit:**

There are a few other issues with your code, namely:

- *you have an uncaught reference error on Line 2 of npm.js.*
  You will need to include either commonJS or requireJS, preferably
  commonJS, in your HTML's header, before you include npm.js. Or, even
  better, take a look at using Webpack, to compile your javascript into
  a single bundle file.

  If you haven't used Webpack before, have a look at this tutorial: https://github.com/AriaFallah/WebpackTutorial
- You are passing an **object** as a *GET* parameter to `ajax.php`, where you need to pass a string. You can fix this by changing your code in `History.Adapter.bind` to the following.
  (**NOTE:** I used a snippet, as the code formatting with both the code tag and the double/triple back-ticks isn't working properly)

```js
History.Adapter.bind('window', 'statechange', function() {
 var State = History.getState();
 var data  = State.data;
 $("#main").fadeOut();

 $.post('/functions/ajax.php', { id: data }, function(response) {
   setTimeout(function() {
      finishAjax('main', escape(response);
      ajaxifyLinks();
    }), 400);
 });
});
```

I also noticed that sometimes the ajaxifyLinks() function was called *before* finishAjax() had been executed, due to the code not being invoked from within setTimeout(). I've restructured things slightly to fix this.

In addition to this, upon inspection, your `State.data` object is actually an empty object, as shown below. You may want to use a different property in the `State` object, or ensure that you add the required data to `State.data`.

[image: Chrome Developer Console - Inspection]

I would strongly recommend having a look at the Firebug (if you use Firefox) or the Chrome Developer Console, if you use Chrome. You can add a breakpoint to the code you want to inspect, and when you interact with your site, it will stop execution when it hits that breakpoint, allowing you to see the value of each variable, etc (as above).

Also, it makes some of these issues very easy to spot. For example, the following image shows how I found the parameter issue. Notice in the red squares that the id is `[object%20object]` (`%20` is URI encoding for 
'space'), whereas in the blue it is a numeric id:

[image]

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I looked into your edit in my fiddle, but it still won't load the previous page when I use $.post.

Comment: @ChinmayNagrale interesting... I'll take another look when I get some time tonight.

Comment: Okay, also make sure you've checked the discussion room between us.

Comment: Have a look at my edit, I found a few other issues. :)

Comment: There was a problem in the setTimeout part, which I corrected, but it still wont work. I have tried changing the code, but then again nothing happens. What I noticed after changing what you suggested, was that I had to click the button twice to get the result.

Comment: It seems like nothing is working, so I'm going to make a whole new ajax call from scratch. Everytime, I get stuck and make everything from scratch works! So, I'll close this question.